# iOS EXC_BAD_ACCESS Crash on Nativescript app

Tags: ios, app-store, nativescript, crash-log

We've made an Android and iOS app and send this through some testing. Our tests found no bugs however when sending it to the App store we got denied and returned a crashlog. I however can't find the bug with the information given.

Can anybody help me translate this crashlog? I've already looked at the [Apple Documentation Archive](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-STACKTRACE) but found no usefull help here.

The header of the crashlog is as follows:

```
{"app_name":"RealityKeeper","timestamp":"2018-09-11 14:18:30.81 -0700","app_version":"1.0","slice_uuid":"261b3ad9-a8bf-3281-a674-cb1501ddcaea","adam_id":1432593416,"build_version":"1.1","bundleID":"org.nativescript.RealityKeeper","share_with_app_devs":false,"is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","os_version":"iPhone OS 11.4 (15F79)","incident_id":"CF7FD300-AED5-4D15-9F74-21F668D25C02","name":"RealityKeeper"}
Incident Identifier: CF7FD300-AED5-4D15-9F74-21F668D25C02
CrashReporter Key:   ba49afbd7a6c374bc5099303e3a251a30ac3555e
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             RealityKeeper [10712]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/3619F4D9-601D-4A05-8F9C-EB7FE9AED112/RealityKeeper.app/RealityKeeper
Identifier:          org.nativescript.RealityKeeper
Version:             1.1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           org.nativescript.RealityKeeper [3565]


Date/Time:           2018-09-11 14:18:30.6327 -0700
Launch Time:         2018-09-11 14:18:27.3888 -0700
OS Version:          iPhone OS 11.4 (15F79)
Baseband Version:    6.60.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000deaddead
VM Region Info: 0xdeaddead is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 561914195
      REGION TYPE                      START - END             [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                 00000001002c0000-00000001002c4000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...RealityKeeper

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: Are you by any chance using notification plugin? Check this thread where a similar problem was resolved pretty much with a clean rebuild https://github.com/NativeScript/push-plugin/issues/30#issuecomment-225429745

Comment: I am using a notification plugin, not the one linked. Those notifications work. The problem is also that I can't even find the bug, I replicated the scenario that the App Store reported but don't get any error or crash.

Comment: @Stefan Could you find a solution. I am facing this too.

Comment: @Stefan can u share your answer?

Comment: Sorry @RageshPikalmunde, I did manage to solve this, but never really found out what was wrong. It appears I also forgot to make an update here. Maybe zarax can help. 

I do know that I used "nativescript-local-notifications". If you have that, or a similar notification plugin, that might be the cause. 
Good luck